# INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE versus client-side flow control: pros and cons

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a SQL table in which I have to insert or update data depending on the existence of the primary key. The context is a CodeIgniter-based PHP web application running on MySQL. I discovered the `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement which perfectly fits my needs but, before that, the code was based upon CI's Active Record implementation and looked like this:

```
$res = $this->db->get_where('table', array('id' => $this->_id));
if(count($res->result_array()) > 0) { // update if present
    $this->db->where(array('id' => $this->_id));
    $this->db->update('table', $hash);
    return 2;
} else { // new entry if not present
    $personal_data['id'] = $this->_id;
    $this->db->insert('table', $hash);
    return 1;
}
```

The other developer in this project asked me to maintain things simple and preferring Active Record code over straight SQL and prepared queries, and after a while thinking about it I'm not sure about what fits best in a situation like this since there are pros and cons in both cases.

For instance, the Active Record solution is very simple from a flow control point of view, but has the big drawback of performance and the even bigger drawback of potential concurrency issues (if the condition stated by the first query changes before the execution of the second query, outcome is unpredictable).

On the other hand, `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works fine and avoids the concurrency issues but is MySQL-only and could result in portability issues, plus is not constructible with CI's Active Record and I'd need a prepared query.

What would the best practice be in this case? Are there other, better ways of achieving the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to let the database handle such constraints for the simple reason that otherwise you need to trust the application to behave.

If you leave it to the database, you can allow any/several applications to manipulate the data without fearing that they break the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another solution to keep CI active record.

```
$query_string = $this->db->insert_string('table', array('id' => $this->_id, 'hash' => $hash));

$this->db->query($query_string.' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hash=VALUES(hash)');
```